# How to automate Google Sheet Email to send within quota and daily?

Tags: email, google-sheets

I have the following Google Script to send emails via Google Sheets.
But I don't want to send beyond the quota.

Instead I want to send within quota (I think its 50 emails at a time) and the next 50 recipients the next day until end of email list.

How do I do that?

```
function sendEmail() {var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var sheet2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();
var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();
var n=sheet1.getLastRow();
for (var i = 2; i < n+1 ; i++ ) {
var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(i,3).getValue();
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

First you would need the script to send only 50 emails per execution. This script would send to the first 50 addresses on the list in `Sheet1` and move them to `Sheet3`, so there is no need to change anything in the code:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');
  var subject = sheet2.getRange(2,1).getValue();
  var message = sheet2.getRange(2,2).getValue();

  var lr1 = sheet1.getLastRow() > 50 ? 50 : sheet1.getLastRow() - 1;
  console.log(lr1);
  var emailAddresses = sheet1.getRange(2,3,lr1).getValues();
  
  var lr3 = sheet3.getLastRow();
  var doneAddresses = sheet3.getRange(lr3+1,3,lr1);

  for (var i=0; i < lr1; i++) {
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddresses[i][0], subject, message);
  }

  doneAddresses.setValues(emailAddresses);
  sheet1.deleteRows(2,lr1);
}
```

Then you need to create an **installable time-based trigger** that runs every 24 hours, or you can also configure it at a specified time:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(24) // or change this to .atHour(8) to run every 8AM
      .create();
}
```

Run this function only once to create this installable trigger. `sendEmail()` will then run daily. Please take note of the restrictions in the documentation.

### Sample Data:

I used a sample sheet with 80 dummy addresses and ran the script once. Of course the email will fail, but the other parts of the script work as expected.

**Sheet1**

[image]

**Sheet3**

[image]

### References:

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

[Clock Trigger Builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder)

Comment: Oh thanks so much. Let me try this. And yes, will keep the restrictions in mind.

Comment: Works, except changed "emailAddresses" to "emailAddress" and `var emailAddress = sheet1.getRange(2,1,lr1).getValues();" ` to the correct row, column. Also "This script would send to the first 50 addresses on the list in Sheet1 and move them to Sheet3" doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a sample sheet after execution, I am not sure how your sheet is constructed, maybe you can include an error message?

Comment: I get it now. I just needed to get the correct cell numbers. Works like a charm now. Thanks so much.

Comment: So The script doesn't run when I am logged out of gmail. It does run, when I click the 'Run' button. I would like it to keep running in the background. Is this happening because I am calling for an active spreadsheet and I instead need to call a spreadsheet by name? `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`